# Getting CUDA out of memory under pytorch in Google Colab

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to replicate the work described here (https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/02/building-crowd-counting-model-python/) in google colab. Unfortunately at first it was working but after a some time it is showing cuda out of memory error for this line of code.

```py
output = model(img.unsqueeze(0))
```

Here is the error description:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 98.00 MiB (GPU 0; 11.17 GiB total capacity; 10.78 GiB already allocated; 40.81 MiB free; 34.25 MiB cached)
```

I tried to run this code in different google account but shows same error.

Comment: Solved now. Problem was that resolution of image was too high. So I decrease the image resolution and now it works fine.

Comment: You could also resolve the issue by lowering the batch size and not the image resolution - as lowering the latter will affect the classification accuracy

Comment: @MuhammadArslan's comment could be placed as an answer. It works.

Answer (score 2):

You could also resolve the issue by lowering the batch size and not the image resolution - as lowering the latter will affect the classification accuracy

Comment: i am running llama2-7b model on a Google Colab on a T4 instance. i have reduced batch size to 1 and still get the CUDA out of memory error.  Has anyone tried running this model on Colab with T4 ?